# laravel 4 command 'class not found'

Tags: laravel-4

I'm create new command "`php artisan command:make mycommand`"

The command was added, but when I try to add "Artisan::add(new mycommand)" in app/start/artisan.php it doesn't work for any command, like "php artisan -V" and show this:

```
[{"error":
{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'mycommand' not 
found","file":"\/usr\/home\/xxxx.com\/htdocs\/local\/app\/start\/artisan.
php","line":15}}[xxx@xxx~/htdocs/local]$ ]
```

I've tried "composer dump-autoload" but also show this:

> [  [RuntimeException]
>   Could not scan for classes inside "app/extensions" which does not
>   appear to be a file nor a folder  ]

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `commands` folder to your composer.json and app/start/global.php files ?

#### global.php

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories ( array (
    app_path () . '/commands',
    ... 
));
```

#### composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply a namespace to your command?